# User Session Data Resets On Redirect (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3, session-cookies

I can see that the problem of session resetting upon redirection can be found in multiple posts on different forums and Q&A sites.

None of the solutions proposed solved my problem. The problem is that user session data gets cleared after redirection (using `window.location.href = SOME_PLACE`).

I am running XAMPP with PHP 7.2.3 and CI 3.0.6.

What I tried:

- Upgrading CI to 3.1.9
- using the value of `localhost` to `cookie_domain`.
- Made sure session library is autoloaded. (Tried manually loading it in the controllers constructors I needed)
- Added value for `sess_save_path` and made sure it's writable by the process owner (actually, I had a look at the generated files).
- Tried Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

What am I missing? Please help me investigate this issue and get to the bottom of it. This is really frustrating.

Comment: Is your php configured as PHP FPM?

Comment: FPM? What does that mean?

Comment: Looked it up. Doesn't seem the case. I just have XAMPP installed with PHP 7.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem. It is a bit strange though.

The problem in my case was that the session expiration date was always the current machine time. So, it gets cleared right after it is created.

The solution is setting `sess_expiration` to `0` (clear session when browser is closed). This is done in `application/config/config.php`:

`$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;`

**UPDATE**

After downgrading CI back to 3.0.6, user session data resets. Upgraded again to 3.1.9 and things started working again. So, along with the configuration change above, upgrading to 3.1.9 is part of the solution.